# ASP.NET MVC The view 'name' or its master was not found

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with a View. Here's the code snippet:

```
    public ActionResult AddAdvertisement()
    {
        ...
        return RedirectToAction("AdvCreated");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AdvCreated()
    {
        return View("AdvCreated", "abc");
    }
```

then I see the error

**The view 'AdvCreated' or its master was not found. The following locations were searched:**

**~/Views/Advertisement/abc.master**

**~/Views/Shared/abc.master**

If I just go to URL http://localhost/AdvCreated everything is OK. Why ?

Comment: He's saying if he hits http://localhost/AddAdvertisement he get's the error.

Answer (score 8):

What I understand is you are trying to pass a string to View as model. It's not possible. There is an overload of View function like this:

```
View(string viewName,string masterViewName)
```

So it looks for a Master View named "abc". If you want to pass a string, convert it to an object.There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178887/i-cant-pass-a-value-to-view/3179073#3179073).

Comment: So, the only way to pass a string to a View is to store it in ViewData ?

Comment: No. You can convert it to an object, then display it just using ToString() method in the View. Check the example I posted and you will see.

Comment: If you're using MVC3 (any release) you can also use .NET 4.0 dynamic propery ViewModel in controllers like ViewModel.MyString = "abc";. You can then access this in the view via View.MyString.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do the following

```
return View("AdvCreated", (object)"abc");
```

Or if you are using .NET 4 you can even do this:

```
return View("AdvCreated", model: "abc");
```

This forces the Framework to use the correct overloadthat treats the second parameter as the model.

Answer (score 1):

Your view/aspx/ascx needs to be located inside one of those folders listed to be used such as the code in your controller.

If you just do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("AdvCreated");
```

ASP.NET MVC will assume you have a view/ascx/aspx located in the your controller folder - in your case ~/Views/Advertisement/ folder or the shared folder.

If you have a specific view to display outside the assumed folders, you can specify that directly, such as:

```
return RedirectToAction("~/MyFolder/AdvCreated.ascx");
```